# Earlier working nested if statement formula no longer working in Google New Sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, spreadsheet

There is a formula (for converting amount in digits into amount in words) which was working fine in the earlier version of Google sheet. In new sheet, it is no longer working and giving the following error :

> Error : Function CHOOSE parameter 1 value is 0. Valid values are between 1 and 19 inclusive.

The formula is a little bigger and complex (multiple if function) - please see the link below the see the formula - (in Cell B2) -

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XdcKbxKvIOSFK37zwULZns6giE9ounHPS5iHrRFkvIk/edit#gid=882895877

`=arrayFormula(concatenate(if(trunc(mod(A2,power(10,{11,9,7,5,3}))/power(10,{9,7,5,3,0}))<100,"",choose(int(trunc(mod(A2,power(10,{11,9,7,5,3}))/power(10,{9,7,5,3,0}))/100)," One"," Two"," Three"," Four"," Five"," Six"," Seven"," Eight"," Nine") & " Hundred") & if(mod(trunc(mod(A2,power(10,{11,9,7,5,3}))/power(10,{9,7,5,3,0})),100)<>0,if(trunc(mod(A2,power(10,{11,9,7,5,3}))/power(10,{9,7,5,3,0}))>100," and",if(A2>power(10,{11,9,7,5,3}),choose({1,2,3,4,5},"","","",""," and"),"")),"") & if(mod(trunc(mod(A2,power(10,{11,9,7,5,3}))/power(10,{9,7,5,3,0})),100)=0,"",if(mod(trunc(mod(A2,power(10,{11,9,7,5,3}))/power(10,{9,7,5,3,0})),100)<20,choose(mod(trunc(mod(A2,power(10,{11,9,7,5,3}))/power(10,{9,7,5,3,0})),100)," One"," Two"," Three"," Four"," Five"," Six"," Seven"," Eight"," Nine"," Ten"," Eleven"," Twelve"," Thirteen"," Fourteen"," Fifteen"," Sixteen"," Seventeen"," Eighteen"," Nineteen"),choose(int(mod(trunc(mod(A2,power(10,{11,9,7,5,3}))/power(10,{9,7,5,3,0})),100)/10),""," Twenty"," Thirty"," Forty"," Fifty"," Sixty"," Seventy"," Eighty"," Ninety") & if(mod(mod(trunc(mod(A2,power(10,{11,9,7,5,3}))/power(10,{9,7,5,3,0})),100),10)=0,""," " & choose(mod(mod(trunc(mod(A2,power(10,{11,9,7,5,3}))/power(10,{9,7,5,3,0})),100),10),"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine")))) & if(trunc(mod(A2,power(10,{11,9,7,5,3}))/power(10,{9,7,5,3,0}))=0,"",choose({1,2,3,4,5}," Arab"," Crore"," Lakh"," Thousand","")))) & " only"`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [CHOOSE Function Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093371) If index is zero, negative, or greater than the number of choices provided, the #VALUE! error is returned.

That being said, I think you could accomplish this task just by counting the digits, and then choosing the word version of each digit by isolating your digits using a series of =RIGHT() functions.

Comment: Hi @Jacob! thanks for your anwer! I am sorry, I am new to this spreadsheet world, and did not get what do you mean by isolating your digits using a series of _=Right()_ function. Could you explain it a little more please. Thank you very much!

Comment: Something like this: =IF(LEN(A1)>3,IFERROR(CHOOSE(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,4),1),"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine"),""),"")